# Can octoprint stream from an on if camera over https or rts

Tags: octoprint

Can octoprint connect to a camera that uses the onvif streaming connection standard over https or rts, as opposed to a direct mjpeg stream over usb?

I have a bunch of onvif camera lying around that I could potentially repurpose to watch my printer.